# SwiftUI Switch Statement Transition Behavior is not as expected

Tags: swiftui, transition, updateview

I am getting unexpected `.transition` behavior when using a `switch` statement to update the View vs. when using two `if` statements. The two `if` statements are sliding the views back in and out as expected, however, the same transitions in the `switch` statement are causing the views to slide in from one side and exit the other.

I am looking to use the `switch` syntax to keep my code consistent (as to how I am updating the view) but get the behavior that is commensurate with the `if` statements.

Here is some example code in which one can observe the Top Rectangles and the Botton Rectangles exhibiting different transition behavior:

```
import SwiftUI

enum ExampleStep: Int {
    
    case stepOne
    case stepTwo
    
}

struct TransitionExample: View {
    
    @State var exampleStep:ExampleStep = .stepOne
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Button {
                
                withAnimation {
                    exampleStep = exampleStep == .stepOne ? .stepTwo : .stepOne
                }
            
            } label: {
                Text("Click Me")
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            if exampleStep == .stepOne {
                
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .leading))

            }
            
            if exampleStep == .stepTwo {
                
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
                
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            switch exampleStep {
                
            case .stepOne:
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                
            case .stepTwo:
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
                
            
            
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
        }
        
    }
    
}

struct TransitionExample_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TransitionExample()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference likely has to do with how the SwiftUI result builder translates the `if` statement into `buildIf`, `buildEither`, etc vs. how the `switch` statements are translated. See: https://jasonzurita.com/swiftui-if-statement/

It looks like you can get the behavior to match the `if` statements if you explicitly define asymmetric transitions in the `switch` statement:

```
switch exampleStep {
    
case .stepOne:
    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(Color.green)
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .leading), removal: .move(edge: .trailing)))
    
case .stepTwo:
    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .trailing), removal: .move(edge: .leading)))
    
}
```

Comment: Thank You.  This solution works.  I would love to understand more on why, so I will definitely be checking out the link you posted